# I want to add css to document.write in js

Tags: javascript, css

```js
document.write("<h1>Elzero</h1>");
```

I want to add this css only using JS :

```css
color: blue;
font-size: 80px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
font-family: Arial;
```

Comment: don’t use document.write! it can trash a page and sometimes is really slow.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] (and earn a badge while at it) - Your question does not indicate what the issue you are facing is.  You need to [edit] and clarify your question.  Read our [ask] page for suggestions on how to improve it

Comment: Please don’t use this platform for announcements, it wastes people’s time. If you have a **question** that meets the site’s standards feel free to ask that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
document.write('<h1 id=item>text</h1>')

const item = document.querySelector('#item')

item.style.color = "blue"
item.style.fontSize = "16px"
... and other
```

But as they said above - it's better not to do